# Setting and getting lua tables from C

Tags: c, lua

Currently I construct and push a table (derived from a C dictionary of key-value pairs) onto the lua stack from C right before calling lua_pcall() to run the script - this part works fine.

But after running the script, I would like to be able to iterate through that same table from C, looking for any changes in order to update the original C dictionary values if needed, all without returning a table in the lua script.

What's the best approach for doing this? Or is there a better way of achieving the same goal of setting and getting the table.

Comment: implementing metamethods `__index` and `__newindex` as C functions and pushing them on to the table.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access it directly like a [pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31132576/is-it-possible-to-access-lua-table-elements-using-a-c-pointer), you need to push it from the lua stack again to be able to access it from C side like in the example.
Another simpler way would involve *luajit* and *ffi library*.